# Android: Having few items in the same context menu as a radio group and few as check-boxes

Tags: android, accessibility

I am trying to create a context menu which should look like

---

### MenuItem1 O

### MenuItem2 O

### MenuItem3 O

### MenuItem4 ✔

### MenuItem5 ✔

Is it possible to do the same? Please note that I know that using setGroupCheckable I can create a group of checkable radio button menuItems, and using setCheckable for individual items, I can get checkbox menuItems but how to get both in the same menu is the issue that I am facing.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html is a good reference for radio buttons and checbox menus.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the way to achieve this, thus, thought of sharing with others.

You can add the various menuItems to the same menu using different group ids and thus, for one group, you can say setGroupCheckable to true (that makes that group of radio buttons) whereas you can make the individual menu items of the other group as checkable (setCheckable(true)), and they become checkboxes.